# Recursive no CakePHP - Explicação

Tags: cakephp, recursão

Gostaria de saber, com explicação em exemplo, como funciona o `recursive` do CakePHP.

```
$this->Model->recursive=2;
```

O que ele faz exatamente, na prática?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive), a propriedade `recursive` define o quão fundo o CakePHP deverá ir para buscar os registros associados a um modelo de dados através dos métodos `find` *e*/*ou* `read`.

> Imagine que a sua aplicação caracteriza *Grupos* que pertencem a um
>   *domínio* que tem vários *Usuários* que por sua vez tem vários *Artigos*.
>
> Você pode definir a propriedade `recursive` com valores diferentes com
>   base na quantidade de dados que você quer retornar de uma chamada, por
>   exemplo `$this->Group->find()`:
>
> - *`-1`* Busca dados apenas do *Grupo*, sem junção.
> - *`0`*  Busca dados do *Grupo* e de seu *domínio*.
> - *`1`* Busca um *Grupo*, seu *domínio* e seus *Usuários* associados.
> - *`2`* Busca um *Grupo*, seu *domínio*, seus *Usuários* associados e os *artigos* associados dos *Usuários*.
>
> O padrão é *`1`*. O nível de recursividade recomendado é *`-1`*. Isso
>   evita retornar dados relacionados que são desnecessários ou até mesmo
>   indesejáveis

Veja também o artigo [Recuperando seus dados](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) <sup>*em inglês*</sup> do *blog* do CakePHP.